# IntelliJ @IfProfileValue default value

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-test

In most projects that use Spring extensively there are a few tests that use @IfProfileValue to mark it as integration test, performance test or similar. When you run these with maven you do something like this:

```
mvn install -Dperformance-test=true
```

for a class annotated like this:

```
@IfProfileValue(name = "performance-test", value = "true")
```

But if I run this test in IntelliJ I get:

```
Test '.Tests in Progress.MyTest' ignored
```

which I can go around in IntelliJ by commenting out the annotation, but I would prefer if the test just ran without having to remove the line, so I don't accidentally commit/push the class without the marker.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the run-configurations and set your parameter `-Dperformance-test=true`
 as VM option.

See the [IDEA Run Config](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-application.html) for detailed info.